# Spatial interpolation of hourly temporal resolution temperature data using QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I would like to spatially interpolate gridded (10X10km) hourly temperature data to a finer spatial grid (e.g. 5X5km). I am talking about 1 year of data (thus 8760 hourly temperatures) for each point of my grid (e.g. 100,000 data points).

I am using QGIS for the interpolation.
First, I have issues in uploading the .txt file in QGIS. The QGIS crashes as soon as I am trying to upload a .txt file with 8762 coloumns (e.g. lon, lat, T1, T2, T3, ..., T8760).

Is there a way to easily uplodad and work on heavy files in QGIS?

Secondly, I have problems with the interpolation. Using for instance IDW, what I get is a raster for each hourly tempererature time-step. On this regard, I have two questions:

1 - Is there a way to automate the procedure using QGIS? Thus, automatically obtaining hourly temperature data interpolated to my finer grid?

2 - Are there other easier procedures/software to obtain the interpolation to a finer grid?

[image: Here you see an example of the first 5 temperature time-steps related to 4 locations]

Comment: This appears to be an interesting project.  However, it would really help if you would edit your question and include the first few lines of your .txt file, or provide  link to the data.  Without a chance to look at the data, any response you would get here would be mostly a guess.

Comment: Two comments: Since you are trying to get 3762 separate interpolations, you will **have to rely on scripting**. I think I see python of R in your near future. In addition, you mention 5km x 5km. Beware that regular intervals in long/lat coordinates will NOT give you square pixels of 5km x 5km.  You might want to first reproject your long/lat grid points onto a suitable Cartesian coordinate system.